# More efficient algorithm for Withdraw/Deposit position in bank statement

Tags: algorithms

I am parsing bank statements where the transaction amount is ambiguous as to the withdraw/deposit nature and the balance is only given periodically.

My goal is to more efficiently, than brute force, find where the possible withdraw/deposit position should be.

For Example:

| Transaction ID | Withdraw/Deposit? | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | \$10 | \$400 |
| 2 | \$10 |  |
| 3 | \$10 |  |
| 4 | \$10 |  |
| 5 | \$10 | \$440 |

In the above example, to go from balance \$400 to \$440, transactions 2 to 5 need to be deposits.

My current algorithm brute forces it by simply testing all possible positional permutations, 16 in the worst case.

Of course this grows exponentially if there are fewer transactions with balances. 18 rows would be 262,144 potential attempts.

Collisions/Multiple answers to ambiguous sets are fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an instance of the [subset-sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).  As such, you can use standard algorithms for the subset-sum problem to find candidate solutions -- e.g., the pseudopolynomial-time algorithm using dynamic programming is probably a reasonable choice.

Suppose the transaction amounts are $a_1,\dots,a_n$.  Let $D$ be the difference in balances.  Then our goal is to find a set $W$ of indices that represent the withdrawals (then $[n]\setminus W$ represents the deposits); this set should satisfy the condition
$$\sum_{i \in W} a_i - \sum_{i \notin W} a_i = D.$$
This is equivalent to the condition
$$\sum_{i \in W} 2 a_i = D + \sum_{i=1}^n a_i.$$
Let $T = D + \sum_{i=1}^n a_i$.  Then $T$ is a known constant, and the goal is to find a subset of $2a_1,\dots,2a_n$ that sum to $T$.  This is exactly the subset-sum problem.

Comment: Ah this is perfect! I didn't know what it was called. Plenty of implementations that are fast enough for my usage. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have $n$ unknown rows, and you started with $L$ money. After the $n$ transactions, you ended up with $L'$ money.

Basically, you want to know which of the $n$ unknown transactions were deposited and which were withdrawn. So, lets denote by $a_i$ the money in transaction $i$.

Our task is to find $s_i\in\{-1,+1\}$ such that: $L + \sum_{i=1}^n s_i\cdot a_i = L'$, or equivalently, $\sum_{i=1}^n s_i\cdot a_i=L'-L$.

If I remember correctly, you can order the $a_i$'s in decreasing order and then apply some greedy algorithm. Im not 100% sure this is correct, but I hope I helped you formalize this question in such a way that can help you think and solve this problem :)